# Stage only deleted files with git add

Tags: git, git-add, git-stage

I have run `git status` and see several modified files and several deleted files.

Is it possible to stage only deleted or only modified files?

Comment: `git status` also tells you how to stage and unstange the new/modified/deleted files.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

If you have a mix of modified and deleted files and only want to stage deleted files to the index, you can use `git ls-files` as a filter.

```
git ls-files --deleted | xargs git add
```

If you only want this to apply to part of the file tree, give one or more subdirectories as arguments to `ls-files`:

```
git ls-files --deleted -- lib/foo | xargs git add
```

To do the same for only modified files, use the `--modified` (`-m`) option instead of `--deleted` (`-d`).

Comment: If the names of the deleted files contain spaces you should pass the parameter `-d "\n"` to xargs.

Comment: You could also use `git ls-files -z --deleted | xargs -0 git add` for filenames with special characters (even newlines).

Comment: Thanks steve - Special characters and space in filenames

Comment: In case you want to add this as an alias to `.gitconfig`, here's a caveat: you must stringify the command and prefix with it `!` like this: `sd = !"git ls-files --deleted | xargs git add"`

Comment: To account for spaces in the filenames, use `git ls-files --deleted | xargs -d '\n' git add --all`

Comment: Windows Powershell I got: `xargs : The term 'xargs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.`

Comment:  Powerful stuff there! First I have heard of `ls-files`.

Answer (score 10):

Same as the [@steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1173869/steve) answer, but adding a little change:

Add **--all** to the end of the command to add all the files returned by the **ls-files** command to the index

```
git ls-files --deleted | xargs git add --all
```

Answer (score 10):

For PowerShell

```
git ls-files --deleted | % {git add $_}
```

Answer (score 5):

For all the love `ls-files` is getting here, it seems to me

```
git add --all $(git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only)
```

is more straightforward.

Comment: This does not work if a path needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D | sed 's| |\\ |g' | xargs git add
```

I use `sed` here because the paths could have whitespace characters.

Comment: This works on OSX!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, you could use the interactive mode `git add -i`, then select `2` to update which files you want to stage and pick only the deleted ones (for example, use a range `1-30`).

It's easier to remember sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to stage only the deleted files

```
git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only -z | xargs -0 git add
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To do it with just core commands, built for scripting:

```
git diff-files -z --diff-filter=D --name-only | git update-index -z --remove --stdin
```