# How do I stage only deleted files in Git for Windows?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

Suppose I run ***git status*** and have deleted, modified, and other changes.

How do I stage only the deleted files?

I have tried the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161383/stage-only-deleted-files-with-git-add):

***git ls-files --deleted | xargs git add***

but this doesn't seem to work under windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stage only deleted files with git add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161383/stage-only-deleted-files-with-git-add)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't provide the `xargs` command and this renders useless most suggestions about how to solve this issue, including those provided in the documentation page of [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) or [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm).

But the documentation of `git rm` suggests one command that can be used to produce a list of commands that can solve this issue. The command is:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D --line-prefix="git rm "
```

It produces the list of the files that were removed from the working tree, one file on each line, and prefixes each file name with `git rm`.

After you run it as-is and inspect its output you can redirect its output to a `.cmd` file (let's say `rm-deleted.cmd`) by appending `> rm-deleted.cmd` to the command line and then run the generated script (`rm-deleted.cmd`) to achieve your goal. You can then remove the script (`del rm-deleted.cmd`); it is not a general tool to be re-used but just a one-time script that deletes from the index a certain list of files.

Read more about the arguments of [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

---

I don't have an instance of Windows at hand and I don't know how Git handles the files that contain spaces in their names. I suspect that this script is not able to operate on such files. If you have files or directories that contain spaces in their names you should open the generated script into a programming editor, replace all occurrences of `git rm` with `git rm "` and append quotes (`"`) after each line (you need a programming editor to be able to search-and-replace the end of lines).

By wrapping the file names in quotes, the Windows Command Prompt passes them correctly to `git rm` and Git is able to identify the files and remove them from the index.