# How to remove the file from git bash screen and also delete that file from repository?

Tags: git

[image: These are my git files]

I have deleted those files from my local repository and then show here as deleted. I also want to remove them from this list. Everytime I use git checkout filename, it removes it from list but it gets restored in the repository also. How can I remove it from the list while keeping the files deleted?

Comment: Pointing to an answer with git filter-branch? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Simple [stage then commit the deleted files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43161383/6309):

```
git add --all $(git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only)
# or
git ls-files --deleted | xargs git add --all
```

Then

```
git commit -m "delete files"
```