# git commit only modified files as atomic commit, then commit only deleted files as separate atomic commit

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a mix of `deleted`, `new` and `modified` files in my `git staging` area,
i.e. they are already all `add`ed to the staging area and are ready to be finally `commit`ted to the repository.

How do I commit file by 'status' instead of using a pathspec?

Example, how do I `commit` (from the `staging` area) only the files that have been `deleted`, but leave `new` and `modified` files alone, in staging?

The reason is because I want to create separate atomic commits with separate comments that are more exact/applicable to the files being committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I would:

- reset the index (no more staged files)
- add them by status, then commit

You can add by status (as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066415/6309)) with:

```
git add --all $(git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only)
```

`D` is for deleted. Use [other filters](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203), like `A` for added or `M` for modified.

Comment: `git reset ...` ?

Comment: @skeetastax yes, a simple `git reset` will empty the staging area, giving you the opportunity to add those files again, this time by status (deleted, added or modified). `git reset` alone (*not* `git reset --hard`, which would also reset the working tree, that is, your files)